# How to run matlab code in linux as script file?

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I am looking into running matlab script in Linux similar to bash/python scripts. I.e., a matlab script that can be run as an application.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a similar effect without your custom `mash` script by adding the following header to the files you want to be executable:

```
#/usr/bin/bash
/path/to/matlab -r "$(sed -n -e '4,$p' < "$0")"
exit $?
```

If you want matlab to terminate after executing the script, as in your example, you could replace the second line with

```
sed -n -e '4,$p' < "$0" | /path/to/matlab
```

The idea here is to execute a bash command that simply clips off the header of the script, and passes the rest along to matlab.

Comment: Better solution than what I came up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation I came up with -

- Create `/usr/bin/mash` script file containing the following lines -

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  grep -ve '^(#!\|^\s*$)' ${@: -1} | ${@: 1:$#-1}     
  exit $?
  ```
- Make mash script executable -

  ```
  $ chmod +x /usr/bin/mash
  ```
- Write matlab script file called `test.msh`

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/mash /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab -nodisplay

  format long

  a = 2*pi           % matlab commands ...
  ```
- Make `test.msh` script executable -

  ```
  $ chmod +x mash
  ```
- Run `test.msh`

  ```
  $ ./test.msh 

  ...

  >> >>  a =

  6.283185307179586
  ```

Comment: Don't put it is `/usr/bin`; `/usr/local/bin` is a better place. `/usr/bin` is distribution-managed folder (or should be).

Comment: When you have code blocks inside lists, you need 8 indentation instead of 4 `;)`.